# Import data from Excel file into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i am trying to import data from an EXCEL file into SQL SERVER. When i run this query

```
SELECT * INTO EXCEL_IMPORT
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 12.0; Database=C:\Users\af\Desktop\Reports\Jan_2016_Ships.xlsx; HDR=YES; IMEX=1',
'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]');
```

I get this error

`The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" has not been registered`.

So i needed to install this driver but after doing some searches i found this :

> Install Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 driver
>
> To import Excel 2007-2016 files to SQL Server Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
>   driver should be installed.
>
> To download the driver use the following link:
>
> Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable
>
> Don't worry about "Access" in the name.
>
> Warning! x64 driver can not be installed if Microsoft Office 2007-2016
>   x86 is already installed!
>
> So there is no way to import Excel data to SQL Server x64 using
>   OPENROWSET/OPENDATASOURCE functions on a machine with Microsoft Office
>   x86!

So i couldn't install this driver because i have SQL SERVER x64 and Microsoft Office x86. I don't want to use the simple import wizard because i have many tables and i need to check the data type of the columns... it will be time consuming in my case.

I believe there should be a solution to run my query on SQL SERVER x64 and Microsoft Office x86.

Any suggestions please ? Thank you very much

Comment: convert file Jan_2016_Ships.xlsx to Jan_2016_Ships.xls then check

Comment: the same error as before

Answer (score 1):

Best way of Import/Export data into Sql Server is Import/Export Wizard facility in SQL Server .

Please refer below link .

http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/feature/The-SQL-Server-Import-and-Export-Wizard-how-to-guide

Thanks .

Comment: thank you for your advice but i am looking for a solution how to run it directly from a query not through the import wizard

Answer (score 0):

If you run it only once you may can run the query in a SSIS package and change the solution to 32bit-mode (right-click the solution, properties, debugging, run64bitRuntime = false)

Answer (score 0):

Is microsoft excel installed in your system?. 
this might solve your problem.

Also you can import to a table manually by SQL management studio.

*right Click on database > Tasks > Import Data*

Comment: thank you for your suggestion but i am looking for a solution how to run it directly from a query

Comment: get driver from this link. install it and try query again. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but i receive the same error when i try to install it "Can not install 64 bit version of MS Database Engine because i have 32 bit office products"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are mixing 32-bit drivers with 64-bit drivers.  This is a big nono.  These two resources are probably your best place to start.

http://www.cnblogs.com/anorthwolf/archive/2012/04/25/2470250.html

http://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-sql-server-import-export-using-vba.htm